# Creating a custom event that captures when a value has changed

Tags: c#, events

I have this small problem. I want to capture every time a property is changed.

This property is wrapped inside another user control:

```
var color = (CustomWPFColorPicker.ColorPickerControlView) elementHost1.Child;
color.CurrentColor <--This property.
```

How can I detect when the CurrentColor property has changed?

Comment: The simple way is to raise an event from the property setter. But I get the feeling you're looking for a more complicated solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Implement [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://INotifyPropertyChanged) on your custom control and raise the `PropertyChanged` event when the given properties change.

The consumer can then register for the `PropertyChanged` event and check the property which raised the event to see if it is the property they care about.

```
public class MyControl : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String info)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
        }
    }

    private Color _color = null;
    public Color CurrentColor
    {
        get
        {
            return _color;
        }

        set
        {
            _color = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("CurrentColor");
        }
    }
}
```

Then the consumer can register for the event and check the property as needed...

```
   MyControl control = new MyControl();
   control.PropertyChanged += OnPropertyChanged;

   void OnPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
   {
      if (e.PropertyName == "CurrentColor")
      {
          //do stuff...
      }
   }
```

Comment: "The consumer can then register for the PropertyChanged" this is the part that has me stuck. How can I register to an event outside of the class? I want to reflect change on the parent form when an event is fired in the child control.

Comment: @Sergio: The event must be exposed publicly, and the parent must subscribe to the child control's event.

Comment: had to mangle with some old code, but I managed to make it work. Thanks a lot for your help! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to check if ColorPickerControlView implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`. If it does attach an handler to `PropertyChanged` event inside `ColorPickerControlView` and then check if the property that has changed is *CurrentColor*:

```
    void myControlPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.PropertyName == "CurrentColor")
        {
            // Do something
        }
    }
```

**EDIT:** If you can modify the custom control try to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`. Hope this example helps:

```
    Color currentColor;
    public Color CurrentColor
    {
        get { return currentColor; }
        set { currentColor = value; OnPropertyChanged("CurrentColor"); }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
```